# Defining a MeshRegion from a list of points and Polygons with duplicate points does not work in 10.4

Tags: bugs, computational-geometry, regions, mesh

**Bug introduced in 10.4.0 and fixed in 11.0**

---

This code produces a `MeshRegion` in versions 10.0 through 10.3.1,

```
MeshRegion[{{0.68, 0.88}, {0.84, 0.85}, {1.12, 0.89}, {0.33, 
   1.13}, {0.81, 0.33}, {0.43, 0.33}, {0.15, 1.13}, {0.96, 
   0.33}, {1.12, 0.33}, {1.12, 1.13}, {-0.12, 0.33}, {-0.12, 
   1.13}}, {Polygon[{1, 5, 8, 2, 1}], Polygon[{3, 9, 8, 2, 3}], 
  Polygon[{6, 11, 12, 7, 6}], Polygon[{1, 2, 3, 10, 4, 1}], 
  Polygon[{1, 5, 6, 7, 4, 1}]}]
```

[image: sample mesh region]

But in version 10.4, it returns the input unevaluated. Is this a bug? Am I not using the proper syntax?

Comment: If you remove the dupe points, it works: `MeshRegion[{{0.68, 0.88}, {0.84, 0.85}, {1.12, 0.89}, {0.33, 1.13}, {0.81, 0.33}, {0.43, 0.33}, {0.15, 1.13}, {0.96, 0.33}, {1.12, 0.33}, {1.12, 1.13}, {-0.12, 0.33}, {-0.12, 1.13}}, {Polygon[{1, 5, 8, 2}], Polygon[{3, 9, 8, 2}], Polygon[{6, 11, 12, 7}], Polygon[{1, 2, 3, 10, 4}], Polygon[{1, 5, 6, 7, 4}]}]`

Comment: @J.M. Yes, this is correct, but there should be a message. I have filed a bug report.

Comment: @J.M.  I mistakenly thought that `Polygon` needed a closed loop, but it apparently will close it itself.  My mistake, should I delete this?

Comment: Had ilian not commented, I would've agreed with removing this. So, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been improved as of version 11.0.0. Now the polygons in the input are reprocessed which results in elimination of the repeated vertices.

[image]